# Will my javascript execute when no client request is made?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, analytics

In my shoppingcart appliction i use google analytics ecommerce for analyzing purchases.

The user pays for the order using ogone. When the user comes back from ogone I handle the order and return a view which contains javascript to post the data to the google servers. This is all working great.

However when a users doesn't return to the website after the payment (by for example closing the browser) The ogone server sends a request with the payment data to a function on my shoppingcart. There i handle te order and return a view with the javascript to post the data to the google servers. But since javascript is executed on client side, will this javascript be executed ? I am not getting any results from this request (the normal one does work)

Any clues or suggestions for a better way to handle ecommerce when the customer doesn't return to the website?

Comment: If it is an **essential** step, I don't think it should be handled at the client-end at all.

Comment: The handling of the order is on server side. However ecommerce api uses javascript. Can i handle this on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the issue you should perform the log operations in your server side code - at the end the entire API is based on HTTP requests and nothing more so you can use `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpClient` class.

I'm assuming that for your purchases analysis you are tracking transactions, in that case there is a ready to use library for you:

- [GaDotNet](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/projects/details/ga-dot-net)

You can use it directly or analyse it source code (available at [GitHub](https://github.com/dougrathbone/Ga.net/blob/master/GaDotNet.Common/Data/GoogleTransaction.cs)) to provide your own implementation.

Comment: GaDotNet didn't work good enough for me. But with you pointing me to it i wrote my own c# wrapper for GA. Thanks for the help! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493455/Server-side-Google-Analytics-Transactions